# How to get user details using the 'alternate email' attribute in Azure AD Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a user in my B2C tenant that has an alternate email present. I would like to retrieve this user's details (specifically the 'signInNames' array) using the 'alternate email' property from the B2C Tenant. I believe this is also known as 'otherMails' when used by Graph API.

I am also using the graph.windows.net URL for the API. If possible, I would like to keep using this URL. If the graph.microsoft.com has a solution for this though, I would like to know about it.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, we went a different route. We ended up saving the email to the "signInNames" field

Answer (score 2):

Try the query as below in the [AAD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/#), it works fine on my side.

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?$filter=otherMails/any(c:c eq 'xxxxxx@xxx.com')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this worked for me.  Can I ask how you figured that out?  Been stuck on this for hours.  Documentation isn't great.